# UV unwrapping with size priority

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm at the UV unwrapping stage of a model, and I've added a bunch of texture seams such that when I perform the automatic UV unwrap, the resulting UVs give me fairly consistent texel density across the model while making pretty efficient use of the texture.

However, the consistent texel density is less than ideal; there are many parts of my model which could benefit from a higher texel density, and other parts where it needs comparatively very little texel density (for example, surfaces that are rarely visible and not looked at closely). It would also be nice if I could give a density boost to sets of polygons within a part of it without breaking it into a separate island or introducing a texture seam (for example, on my character's face).

Is there any way to indicate to Blender that certain faces need more or less detail on average, so that the automated UV unwrap can automatically scale the respective islands (or even faces within the islands) up and down as appropriate?

Alternatively, is there a plugin where I can simply scale the already-unwrapped islands up and down myself and then have it automatically repack the islands without otherwise modifying them? This would be less ideal but it would still save me a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

Recent-ish changes (4.01?) have added the feature you're looking for into out-of-the-box Blender.

Scale islands as desired to create more or less texel density, then use a pack islands operation and disable scale:

[image]

Blender will keep the scale you've provided for your islands and try to pack them into the space.  (You may need to adjust the scale of all objects to get them to fit-- Blender won't maintain existing scale ratios, it just won't scale them at all.)

> It would also be nice if I could give a density boost to sets of polygons within a part of it without breaking it into a separate island or introducing a texture seam

You can do it with a scale of some UV faces with proportional editing enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a good semi-manual workflow, where I performed a standard UV unwrap, then scaled the islands based on requested texel density, and then finally ran [UVPackMaster](https://uvpackmaster.com/) (paid, $39 at the time of this writing) on it, which did an amazing job of optimizing the layout and maximizing the texture usage.